# WordPress primary menu is not shown on all pages

Tags: wordpress, menu, custom-wordpress-pages

I am new to WordPress, and using its GUI elements only. 
I am not familiar with the code behind it.

Currently I created a primary menu and defined it to be the *Primary Menu*, but when I am adding new pages, this menu is not showing on these pages.

Am I suppose to add a *menu-Container* on top of each new page and manually insert the menu to it, or is the Primary menu suppose to appear automatically on all pages?

I should say that I already tried few Themes during this test process and maybe this caused this issue (?)

Thanks for any tip

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

Apparently my default theme - the one that I used initially - did no handle the *Header/Footer* correctly.

In order to fix it I had to do:

1. Load different theme,
2. Open each problematic page with *Elementor* editor,
3. On the left 'Page Settings' panel select *Settings* (on the top-left),
4. On the bottom of this page select *Settings* (again),
5. In the drop-down list named 'Page Layout' select my new theme

[image]

This done the trick